# Small doubt in derivation of double summation formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

I was reading about double summation of series when the variable are dependent.

My book derived the the formula by creating a matrix to identify a pattern in the series:

[image]

Then they derive the formula:

[image]

What I am having trouble understanding is the range in the red box.

How can the range be $0 \leq i < j \leq n$ when the initial values for both $i$ and $j$ is $1$?

Is it a typo in the book? If we had some functions in place of $i$ and $j$, would the discrepancy in initial values matter? If it is not an error, then what is it that I am not getting?

Answer (score 1):

The first summation handle the case where $i \ne j$.

The second part of the summation handle the case when $i=j$.

Comment: I understand that. My problem is shouldn't the first part begin from $i=1$ (instead of $i=0$ as given in the book)?

Comment: I see, fortunately, if you multiply with $0$, it doesn't add anything to the sum. so ya, you could have started from $1$.

Comment: So it means the book is wrong then? What if instead of just $i$ and $j$, there were functions? Then would not the entire sum be wrong just cause I took the wrong initial values?

Comment: if $i=0$, $ij=0$, so it wouldn't affect the sum.  $0+1=1$.

Comment: Ok. But what if we were to replace $i$ and $j$ by $f(i)$ and $f(j)$? Then would this still be valid?

Comment: in that case, you have to be more cautious and use the right indices. note that in most programming languages, we start counting from $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in pair $(i,j)$ are equal, $i=j$, only on so called **"main" diagonal** from left upper corner to right down one.

This diagonal splits square in two triangles: **left down** triangle, where indexes starts from $i=2$(row) and $j=1$(column). In all pairs here we have $i \gt j$; **right upper** triangle, where indexes starts  from $i=1$(row) and $j=2$(column). In all pairs here we have $i \lt j$.

Generally there are three sums accordingly to **"main" diagonal**, **left down** triangle and **right upper** triangle. When in triangles we have same elements, for example, when matrix is symmetric, then we obtain doubled sum for $i \ne j$, which is first in your formula.

Comment: I get that. I am asking about the starting value of $i$ for the triangles, which according to part of the formula I have highlighted is $0$. How can they take it to be $0$ when the series begin from $1$ for both $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @Alpha Delta. If you add summand which contains factor with $i=0$ or $j=0$, then this doesn't change sum, right?

Comment: The sum changes if instead of just $i$ and $j$, $f(i)$ or $f(j)$ is used

Comment: @Alpha Delta. Of course if/when you write other sum, then it changes. No? If you change summand $i\cdot j$ on something another, $f(i)\cdot f(j)$ for example, then, generally, it will not be same for zero indexes.